# JPA + Hibernate + MySQL, ¿Cómo solucionar error entre relaciones de tres tablas uno a muchos?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Sucede que tengo la siguiente estructura de base de datos, este es el modelo:

[image: Modelo Base de Datos]

Estuve usando Java 17 con Hibernate 6.0.0Final y Persistance 2.2.1.

Para arreglar las primeras clases modifique el *@JoinColumn* y lo cambie por un *@JoinColumns* en la tabla **temperaturas** puesto que fallaba ya que se encontraba "incompleto", error arreglado:

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.9.v20210604-2c549e2208): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.9.v20210604-2c549e2208): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [pruebas_MySQL80-Test_jar_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.9.v20210604-2c549e2208): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field medicion] from the entity class [class pruebas.DAO.Temperaturas] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
```

Una solución que intente fue cambiar el tipo de datos de las clases de List a Collections, no funcionó.

Con tal de obtener la *NamedQuery* **FindAll** de cada tabla tuve que realizar algunos cambios en las tablas *medicion* y *temperaturas*, pero no he podido ejecutar la *NamedQuery* de esas dos tablas debido a un error en sintaxis de SQL, esto por Hibernate, en específico añade **id_estacion** en la consulta a la tabla **temperaturas**, como esta columna no existe genera el siguiente error(resumido) al ejecutar la **NamedQuery** de la tabla **medicion**:

```
[EL Info]: 2022-04-27 01:49:45.519--ServerSession(1119072377)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.9.v20210604-2c549e2208
[EL Warning]: 2022-04-27 01:49:45.808--ServerSession(1119072377)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.9.v20210604-2c549e2208): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id_estacion' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT id_registro, fecha, temp_max, temp_min, id_estacion FROM temperaturas WHERE ((id_estacion = ?) AND (id_registro = ?))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="temperaturas" referenceClass=Temperaturas sql="SELECT id_registro, fecha, temp_max, temp_min, id_estacion FROM temperaturas WHERE ((id_estacion = ?) AND (id_registro = ?))")
```

Mientras que por otro lado al hacerlo en la tabla **temperaturas** este es el error:

```
[EL Info]: 2022-04-27 01:51:51.848--ServerSession(849198527)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.9.v20210604-2c549e2208
[EL Warning]: 2022-04-27 01:51:52.113--UnitOfWork(1902801188)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.9.v20210604-2c549e2208): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id_estacion' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT id_registro, fecha, temp_max, temp_min, id_estacion FROM temperaturas
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Temperaturas.findAll" referenceClass=Temperaturas sql="SELECT id_registro, fecha, temp_max, temp_min, id_estacion FROM temperaturas")
```

A continuación comparto código de clase Medicion obviando cierta información:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "medicion")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Medicion.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM Medicion m"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Medicion.findByIdRegistro", query = "SELECT m FROM Medicion m WHERE m.medicionPK.idRegistro = :idRegistro"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Medicion.findByDispositivo", query = "SELECT m FROM Medicion m WHERE m.dispositivo = :dispositivo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Medicion.findByAltura", query = "SELECT m FROM Medicion m WHERE m.altura = :altura"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Medicion.findByIdEstacion", query = "SELECT m FROM Medicion m WHERE m.medicionPK.idEstacion = :idEstacion")})
public class Medicion implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected MedicionPK medicionPK;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "dispositivo")
    private String dispositivo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "altura")
    private int altura;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_estacion", referencedColumnName = "id_estacion", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Estaciones estaciones;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "medicion")
    private Temperaturas temperaturas;

    [...]
```

Comparto código de clase MedicionPK obviando cierta información:

```
@Embeddable
public class MedicionPK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_registro")
    private int idRegistro;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_estacion")
    private int idEstacion;

    [...]
```

Comparto código de clase Temperaturas obviando cierta información:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "temperaturas")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Temperaturas.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Temperaturas t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Temperaturas.findByIdRegistro", query = "SELECT t FROM Temperaturas t WHERE t.idRegistro = :idRegistro"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Temperaturas.findByFecha", query = "SELECT t FROM Temperaturas t WHERE t.fecha = :fecha"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Temperaturas.findByTempMin", query = "SELECT t FROM Temperaturas t WHERE t.tempMin = :tempMin"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Temperaturas.findByTempMax", query = "SELECT t FROM Temperaturas t WHERE t.tempMax = :tempMax")})
public class Temperaturas implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_registro")
    private Integer idRegistro;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "fecha")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fecha;
    @Column(name = "temp_min")
    private String tempMin;
    @Column(name = "temp_max")
    private String tempMax;
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_registro", referencedColumnName = "id_registro", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_estacion", referencedColumnName = "id_estacion", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Medicion medicion;

    [...]
```

¿Alguna idea de como arreglar ese error?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN:**
Debido a un error durante la creación de la estructura de la base de datos, manifestado en la tabla *medicion*, se presentaba un conflicto que resultaba en la inclusión del llamado de la llave primaria *id_estacion* en la tabla *temperaturas*, pero ya que en esta no existe dicha columna, se producía la excepción interna por error de sintaxis. Reestructurando la creación de la tabla queda de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera se elimina la clase *MedicionPK*, la clase *Medicion* resulta en:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "medicion")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Medicion.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM Medicion m"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Medicion.findByIdRegistro", query = "SELECT m FROM Medicion m WHERE m.idRegistro = :idRegistro"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Medicion.findByDispositivo", query = "SELECT m FROM Medicion m WHERE m.dispositivo = :dispositivo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Medicion.findByAltura", query = "SELECT m FROM Medicion m WHERE m.altura = :altura")})
public class Medicion implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_registro")
    private Integer idRegistro;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "dispositivo")
    private String dispositivo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "altura")
    private int altura;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_estacion", referencedColumnName = "id_estacion")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Estaciones idEstacion;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "medicion")
    private Temperaturas temperaturas;
```

Y por otro lado la clase *Temperaturas* ahora es:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "temperaturas")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Temperaturas.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Temperaturas t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Temperaturas.findByIdRegistro", query = "SELECT t FROM Temperaturas t WHERE t.idRegistro = :idRegistro"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Temperaturas.findByFecha", query = "SELECT t FROM Temperaturas t WHERE t.fecha = :fecha"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Temperaturas.findByTempMin", query = "SELECT t FROM Temperaturas t WHERE t.tempMin = :tempMin"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Temperaturas.findByTempMax", query = "SELECT t FROM Temperaturas t WHERE t.tempMax = :tempMax")})
public class Temperaturas implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_registro")
    private Integer idRegistro;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "fecha")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fecha;
    @Column(name = "temp_min")
    private String tempMin;
    @Column(name = "temp_max")
    private String tempMax;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_registro", referencedColumnName = "id_registro", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Medicion medicion;
```